# Cancel button Icefaces with immediate=true

Tags: icefaces

I have a form with save and cancel buttons, cancel button has immediate=true but it doesn't clear the submitted values in the form. I google it and I found this page http://jira.icefaces.org/browse/ICE-1343;jsessionid=2996E8791051E9D6775348E6CE1BC118, it says that the solution is to put an action listener in the cancel button that calls a function that clear the submitted values, it works partially because when I have other tags like panels it doesn't clear them.
Any solution? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out the solution presented here : http://www.icefaces.org/JForum/posts/list/13807.page

I personally haven't found a good solution beside the two most obvious ones : manually traverse the UI components and nullify them

Answer (score 0):

We used `partialSubmit="true"` without setting the immediate attribute to true. This works in `Icefaces` 1.8.2, but there is one drawback. If the validation failed once, it will be executed always.

With `Icefaces 2.x`, the suggested way is to use `singleSubmit="true"`, but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I use immediate="true" and partialSubmit="true" on cancel and something like this for actionListener

```
 public void cancelPopup(ActionEvent event) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
    }
```